# Error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, web-scraping

While trying to extract some text and removing it `escape characters` via this [site](http://yoruba.unl.edu/yoruba.php-text=1a&view=0&uni=0&l=1.htm) , i got some errors any help will be appreciated.
Also the error is applicable to the second loop and i'm using `strip` to remove the `escape characters`. I want to append `['We prepare the saddle, and the goat presents itself; is it a burden for the lineage of goats?','You have been crowned a king, and yet you make good-luck charms; would you be crowned God?','We lift a saddle and the goat (kin) scowls; it is no burden for a sheep.']` to `list` and `the text in the bracket` to another `list`

```
html = '
<p xmlns:ino="http://namespaces.softwareag.com/tamino/response2" xmlns:xq="http://namespaces.softwareag.com/tamino/XQuery/result" xmlns:xql="http://metalab.unc.edu/xql/">
A di g&#224;&#225;r&#236; s&#237;l&#232;&#803; ew&#250;r&#233;&#803; &#324;y&#7885;j&#250;; &#7865;r&#249; &#236;ran r&#232;&#803; ni?<br>
We prepare the saddle, and the goat presents itself; is it a burden for the lineage of goats?<br>
(Goats that know their place do not offer their backs to be saddled.)<br>
This is a variant of A gb&#233; g&#224;&#225;r&#236; &#7885;m&#7885; ew&#250;r&#233;&#803; &#324;roj&#250; . . .<br>
</p>  

<p xmlns:ino="http://namespaces.softwareag.com/tamino/response2" xmlns:xq="http://namespaces.softwareag.com/tamino/XQuery/result" xmlns:xql="http://metalab.unc.edu/xql/">
A fi o&#769;&#803; j&#7885;ba &#242; &#324;&#7779;&#224;w&#250;re o f&#233;&#803; j&#7865; &#7884;lo&#769;&#803;run ni?<br>
You have been crowned a king, and yet you make good-luck charms; would you be crowned God?<br>
(Being crowned a king is about the best fortune a mortal could hope for.)<br>
</p>

<p xmlns:ino="http://namespaces.softwareag.com/tamino/response2" xmlns:xq="http://namespaces.softwareag.com/tamino/XQuery/result" xmlns:xql="http://metalab.unc.edu/xql/">
A fij&#243; gba Aw&#224;; a f&#236;j&#224; gba Aw&#224;; b&#237; a &#242; b&#225; j&#243;, b&#237; a &#242; b&#225; j&#224;, b&#237; a b&#225; ti gba Aw&#224;, k&#242; t&#225;n b&#237;?<br> 
By dancing we take possession of Aw&#224;; through fighting we take possession of Aw&#224;; if we neither dance nor fight, but take possession of Aw&#224; anyway, is the result not the same?<br>
(Why make a huge production of a matter that is easily taken care of?)<br>
</p>

<p xmlns:ino="http://namespaces.softwareag.com/tamino/response2" xmlns:xq="http://namespaces.softwareag.com/tamino/XQuery/result" xmlns:xql="http://metalab.unc.edu/xql/">
A gb&#233; g&#224;&#225;r&#236; &#7885;m&#7885; ewur&#7865; &#324;roj&#250;; k&#236; &#237; &#7779;e &#7865;r&#249; &#224;g&#249;nt&#224;n.<br>
We lift a saddle and the goat (kin) scowls; it is no burden for a sheep.<br>
(The goat has no cause to scowl, because no one will condescend to ride it anyway.)<br>
This is a variant of A di g&#224;&#225;r&#236; s&#237;l&#232;&#803; . . .<br>
</p>'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = request.get(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')

edu = {'Yoruba':[],'Translation':[],'Meaning':[]}

for i in range(0,220):
    # first loop
    for br in soup.select('p > br:nth-of-type(2)'):
        text = br.previous_sibling
        edu['Translation'].append(text.strip())
    # second loop
    for br in soup.select('p > br:nth-of-type(3)'):
        text = br.previous_sibling.strip()
        edu['Meaning'].append(text)
```

Error

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-186-6a48c8c3b845> in <module>
      9     for br in soup8.select('p > br:nth-of-type(2)'):
     10         text = br.previous_sibling
---> 11         edu['Translation'].append(text.strip())
     12     # third loop
     13     for br in soup8.select('p > br:nth-of-type(3)'):```
````

Comment: You can't strip a list instead you can strip the items of the list.

Comment: `append` doesn't return anything that you could `strip`. Did you perhaps mean `append(text.strip())`…?

Comment: So now `text` appears to be `None`…? Because there's no `previous_sibling`? You simply need to expect that situation and test for it, e.g. `if not text: ...`.

Comment: @deceze after adding `if not text:` the `list` was empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append` doesn't have `return` statement so it returns `None`. Call `strip()` on the inserted value instead. You should also add a check if the returned value is `str`

```
for i in range(0,220):
    # first loop
    for br in soup.select('p > br:nth-of-type(2)'):
        text = br.previous_sibling
        if isinstance(text, str):
            edu['Translation'].append(text.strip())

    # second loop
    for br in soup.select('p > br:nth-of-type(3)'):
        text = br.previous_sibling
        if isinstance(text, str):
            edu['Meaning'].append(text.strip())
```

Comment: the error is still the same

Comment: @olaniyanoluwasegun So `br.previous_sibling` probably returned `None`. if you post the relevant html I can have look.

Comment: i had done  update to my question

Comment: @olaniyanoluwasegun I used `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')` instead of the request (I assume `html` is not really part of the code) and it ran fine. Are you sure you are running the correct file?

Comment: here is the [link](http://yoruba.unl.edu/yoruba.php-text=1a&view=0&uni=0&l=1.htm) for the full text

Comment: Thanks. I tried putting them into a dataframe but the length for `Translation` and `meaning` are different

Comment: @olaniyanoluwasegun This is a new question that can't be answered properly in the comments, post a new question with the relevant code and the problem description.

Comment: Hi @Guy , you can also contribute [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59971913/why-is-the-lengtht-not-the-same), Thanks