# What is the best way to extract this data

Tags: python, web-scraping

Looking at the [site](http://yoruba.unl.edu/yoruba.php-text=1a&view=0&uni=0&l=1.htm), i suppose not to see an error because each **local language(Yoruba)** as it **Meaning** and **Translation**, and there are 220 **local language(Yoruba)**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re

res = requests.get('http://yoruba.unl.edu/yoruba.php-text=1a&view=0&uni=0&l=1.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')

edu = {'Yoruba':[],'Translation':[],'Meaning':[]}
    # first loop
for br in soup.select('p > br:nth-of-type(1)'):
    text = br.previous_sibling.strip()
    edu['Yoruba'].append(text)
    # second loop
for br in soup.select('p > br:nth-of-type(2)'):
    text = br.previous_sibling
    if isinstance(text, str):
        edu['Translation'].append(text.strip())
    # third loop
for br in soup.select('p > br:nth-of-type(3)'):
    text = br.previous_sibling
    if isinstance(text, str):
        edu['Meaning'].append(re.sub(r'[\(\)]','',str(text.strip())))

df7 = pd.DataFrame(edu)
```

Error

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Comment: Does that page use javascript to dynamically alter its content?  If so, you can't use requests.

Comment: can you print out the length of each edu key to confirm?

Comment: "pd" is not defined. Give us the complete code and log.

Comment: @matinsoleimani I had updated the question

Comment: @alirezatajadod the length of each key is different

Answer (score 0):

Since each of the three keys has different length, I guess the best way to address it is to pad the short keys to the length of the longest key (220, in this case). To do that add the following right before creating your dataframe:

```
length = max(len(edu['Meaning']),len(edu['Translation']),len(edu['Yoruba'])) #in case you don't know, find the length of the longest key
for k in edu:
    for i in range(length-len(edu[k])):
        edu[k].append("NA") # this is where the padding is; you can replacing NA with anything else, obviously

df7 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(edu) #since edu is a dictionary, I would use this method
df7
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: it worked but the issue i am having is they are to have the same length, looking at the [site](http://yoruba.unl.edu/yoruba.php-text=1a&view=0&uni=0&l=1.htm)

Comment: @olaniyanoluwasegun - I think I figured it out and indeed the answer doesn't work. The problem is with the `text = br.previous_sibling` in each of the 3 loops. Randomly in the html, an `<a>` tag (and sometimes more than)  is/are inserted right before the `<b>` tag. So the the `br.previous_sibling` doesn't take you to the text, but to that `<a>` tag. So to get to that text you would need something like `br.previous_sibling.previous_sibling` or even more. Sorry about that. Once you read this, I'll delete the answer.

Comment: @olaniyanoluwasegun - Also, this assumes that all the `<p>` tags have 3 `<br>` children, but some have 4 while others have only 2.